# what does it mean when someone says "it is one of the ones"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Marriage is **one of the ones** to keep couple committed for lifetime.

I want clarity on the usage of word **ones** here?

Comment: @Nik explains what the speaker probably **means**; but this is not idiomatic English.

Answer (score 3):

Your example sentence is not quite idiomatic (you need to say **couples** or **a couple**).

**Ones**  refers to an antecedent noun, but your sentence has no such context.

**ones** refers to a set of X, where X is established by an antecedent noun.
**one** refers to a member of a set.  **The ones** refers to a subset.

Consider the following:

> Marcos had many dresses. The *ones* she wore on state occasions were
>   very expensive. This is *one* of the *ones* she wore when visiting the
>   White House.

The (particular dresses) she wore on state occasions were very expensive. This is (a member)  of the (set of dresses) she wore when visiting...

> I like apples, but I don't like yellow ones. Can I have one of the red ones?
>
> He likes that director's movies, especially the ones involving espionage.

.

Comment: Among good answers, this is one of the ones. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the word **ones** with the word **things** and the meaning is the same:

> "Marriage is one of the things which keeps a couple committed for a lifetime."

The phrase "one of the ones" means one thing from a group of things you could consider it a less formal and more uncertain or ambiguous way of saying the following:

> "Marriage is one of the five things which keeps a couple committed for a lifetime."

If you say one of the ones, you do not necessarily know how many ones there are in total making it less certain and ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

From all of the things happened between couple's life, marriage is one of the ones will make couple committed to each other.

Here, ones is related to all things that happen in couple's life and marriage is one which will stand out to be reason for committing to each other.